# Using a query string in excel hyperlink

Tags: php, excel

I have a PHP script that exports a report to an excel sheet. After the report is exported, I’d like to be able to clink the link on the excel sheet just the same as if I were on the web page and get to the information. The problem seems to be with the query string in the hyperlink. The question mark and everything behind it does not flow into the web address.  For example:

```
http://mysite/users.php?Selected=Chris Smith
```

brings up just

```
http://mysite/users.php
```

Using

```
=HYPERLINK("http://mysite/users.php?Selected=Chris Smith","Chris Smith")
```

Does not work either. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
=HYPERLINK("http://mysite/users.php?Selected=Chris%20Smith","Chris Smith")
```

Has the same result, ? is cut off.

Comment: Is it possible that the querystring is being passed but then a redirect from the server changes the URL? Try monitoring the request with (eg) Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is seeing the space as the end of the link. You need to `urlencode` the selected attribute first - that would result in:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://mysite/users.php?Selected=Chris%20Smith","Chris Smith")
```